# pip install tesserocr fails with error " Failed building wheel for tesserocr"

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, tesseract, python-tesseract

> I already have the latest builds for leptonica and tesseract
>
> ```
> tesseract 4.00.00alpha-365-gcf0b378
>  leptonica-1.74.1
>   libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0) : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8
> ```

i have also installed all dependencies like python-dev

> This the error i'm getting when i do pip install tesserocr in my
>   virtualenv

```
Collecting tesserocr
      Using cached tesserocr-2.1.3.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: tesserocr
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tesserocr ... error
      Complete output from command /home/ajay/virtualenvs/v2/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-L3JmI9/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpUIPX1spip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Supporting tesseract v4.00.00dev
      Configs from pkg-config: {'libraries': ['lept', 'tesseract'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 262144}, 'library_dirs': ['/usr/local/lib'], 'include_dirs': ['/usr/local/include']}
      cythoning tesserocr.pyx to tesserocr.cpp
      building 'tesserocr' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tesserocr.o
      cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
      In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/genericvector.h:29:0,
                       from tesserocr.cpp:449:
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h: In member function ‘void tesseract::TRand::set_seed(const string&)’:
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h:50:5: error: ‘hash’ is not a member of ‘std’
           std::hash<std::string> hasher;
           ^
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h:50:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
           std::hash<std::string> hasher;
                                ^
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h:50:28: error: ‘hasher’ was not declared in this scope
           std::hash<std::string> hasher;
                                  ^
      tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘tesseract::TessResultRenderer* __pyx_f_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI__get_renderer(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, __pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*)’:
      tesserocr.cpp:16699:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, const char*)’
             __pyx_t_7 = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.GetDatapath());
                                                                                                                ^
      tesserocr.cpp:16699:106: note: candidates are:
      In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const char*, const char*, bool)
         TessPDFRenderer(const char* outputbase, const char* datadir, bool textonly);
         ^
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&)
       class TESS_API TessPDFRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                      ^
      /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for tesserocr
      Running setup.py clean for tesserocr
    Failed to build tesserocr
    Installing collected packages: tesserocr
      Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error
        Complete output from command /home/ajay/virtualenvs/v2/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-L3JmI9/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6eGBXb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ajay/virtualenvs/v2/include/site/python2.7/tesserocr:
        running install
        running build
        running build_ext
        Supporting tesseract v4.00.00dev
        Configs from pkg-config: {'libraries': ['lept', 'tesseract'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 262144}, 'library_dirs': ['/usr/local/lib'], 'include_dirs': ['/usr/local/include']}
        skipping 'tesserocr.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
        building 'tesserocr' extension
        creating build
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
        x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tesserocr.o
        cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
        In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/genericvector.h:29:0,
                         from tesserocr.cpp:449:
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h: In member function ‘void tesseract::TRand::set_seed(const string&)’:
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h:50:5: error: ‘hash’ is not a member of ‘std’
             std::hash<std::string> hasher;
             ^
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h:50:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
             std::hash<std::string> hasher;
                                  ^
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/helpers.h:50:28: error: ‘hasher’ was not declared in this scope
             std::hash<std::string> hasher;
                                    ^
        tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘tesseract::TessResultRenderer* __pyx_f_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI__get_renderer(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, __pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*)’:
        tesserocr.cpp:16699:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, const char*)’
               __pyx_t_7 = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.GetDatapath());
                                                                                                                  ^
        tesserocr.cpp:16699:106: note: candidates are:
        In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const char*, const char*, bool)
           TessPDFRenderer(const char* outputbase, const char* datadir, bool textonly);
           ^
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:190:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&)
         class TESS_API TessPDFRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                        ^
        /usr/local/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
        error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

> I get this error at the bottom

```
        ----------------------------------------
    Command "/home/ajay/virtualenvs/v2/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-L3JmI9/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6eGBXb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ajay/virtualenvs/v2/include/site/python2.7/tesserocr" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-L3JmI9/tesserocr/
```

Comment: did you got the solution?

Comment: if you are running ubuntu 14.04 
try building tesseract 3.04 from source it worked for me

Comment: Tried but this did not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue

completely removed tesseract and leptonica from the system and built everything from source

the debian package leptonica-dev for ubuntu 14.04 was the problem

these are the current builds i've compiled

```
$ tesseract -v
tesseract 3.04.01
 leptonica-1.74.1
  libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0) : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8
```